# Wordpress downloader and unpacker

Tags: bash, wordpress

Wrote a small bash-script today that downloads the latest swedish **wordpress** archive , extracts it and writes wp-config.php

Would appreciate any feedback that could **improve** it / **prettify** it.

The script assumes that the database name & the username is always the same.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Download wordpress tar.gz
echo "Laddar ner senaste wordpress på svenska"
tarfile=$(curl -s https://sv.wordpress.org/ | grep -ioE "https:\/\/sv.wordpress.org\/wordpress-[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]-sv_SE.tar.gz")
wget $tarfile -O senaste_wp.tar.gz
tar xvfz senaste_wp.tar.gz -C ./
rm senaste_wp.tar.gz

# Move the wordpress files to this dir
mv wordpress/* .
rm -r wordpress

# Get wordpress salts
salts=$(curl https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/)

# Read userinput
read -p "Ange databasanvändare : " dbuser
read -p "Ange databaslösenord : " dbpass

# Write wp-config.php
cat > wp-config.php << EOF
define('DB_NAME', '$dbuser');
define('DB_USER', '$dbuser');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '$dbpass');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

$salts

\$table_prefix  = 'wp_';

define('WP_DEBUG', false);

if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
        define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
EOF
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to escape slashes for `grep`, you can simplify to:

```
tarfile=$(curl -s https://sv.wordpress.org/ | grep -ioE "https://sv.wordpress.org/wordpress-[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]-sv_SE.tar.gz")
```

`curl` and `wget` are too similar tools. Consider using only one of them, to reduce the number of dependencies of your script.

Instead of this:

> ```
> wget $tarfile -O senaste_wp.tar.gz
> tar xvfz senaste_wp.tar.gz -C ./
> rm senaste_wp.tar.gz
> ```

You can pipe directly to `tar`, without needing a temporary file, like this:

```
curl $tarfile | tar xvz
```

Lastly, your script is not using anything Bash specific, so you could change the shebang line to `!#/bin/sh`.